# Is there a way of identifying special missing values in a proc format in SAS?

Tags: sas, format, missing-data

I have something similar to the following code going on:

```
 proc format;
 ** for numeric variables;
 value missf
 . = ‘Missing’
 other = ‘Non-Missing’
 ;

 ** for character variables;
 value $missf
 ‘ ‘ = ‘Missing’
 other = ‘Non-Missing’
 ;
 run;

 proc freq data=rawds;
 table _all_ / missing;
 format _character_ $missf. _numeric_ missf.;
 run;
```

As you can see, we have the format `missf` for numeric values. However, my data has special missing values (`.A`, `.B`, `.C`, etc), which currently don't get flagged as missing because the format `missf` only looks for `.`.

I understand I could just add more rows into the proc format, i.e. do something like this, but it feels inefficient:

```
. = 'Missing'
.a = 'Missing'
.b = 'Missing'
.c = 'Missing'
...
.A = 'Missing'
...
.Z = 'Missing'
```

Is there a way of adding in special missing values without having to write 52 lines of code (26 lower case letters, 26 upper case letters)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing values have an order `._` is the smallest, then regular missing, `.`, and then `.A` to `.Z`.

```
value missf ._-.z = 'Missing' other='Non-missing' ;
```

Or you could use LOW-HIGH range to capture the non-missing values and the OTHER case for the missing values.

```
value missf low-high='Non-missing' other='Missing';
```

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else that's wondering, a regular '.' also counts in that missing value order. So all I did was replace `value missf . = ‘Missing’` with `value missf ._-.z = 'Missing'` and it worked fine.